# appcmd.exe to add/change mime type for a subdirectory of a website

Tags: iis, powershell, mime, appcmd

I read from [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28WS.10%29.aspx)  to add mime for IIS 7

```
appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension=' .xyz ',mimeType=' application/octet-stream ']"
```

But if I want to apply the mime settings only to a virtual directory  , how to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a virtual directory, or just a regular subdirectory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve the same problem just now by adding my web app's "site name" as a parameter right after "config." Not sure if it's different if your virtual directory is not its own app.

```
appcmd set config "My Site Name" /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension='.xyz ',mimeType='application/octet-stream ']"
```

Answer (score 1):

The appcmd syntax to add a mime type for a specific folder is like this

```
appcmd set config "Default Web Site/MyFolder" /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension='.* ',mimeType='application/octet-stream ']"
```

to remove a mime type for a specific folder (/- instead of /+)

```
appcmd set config "Default Web Site/MyFolder" /section:staticContent /-"[fileExtension='.* ',mimeType='application/octet-stream ']"
```

Change "Default Web Site" to the name of your website